# Data being referred from parent ajax call issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function inside another ajax function

```
        $.ajax({
              url: '../...',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'JSON',                         
              success: function(data){
                      if (data.length) {

                     // complex and unreadable code
                    // cannot be posted here.

                      $.ajax({
                      url: '../library/index.php?action=librarydetailssearch',
                      type: 'POST',
                      dataType: 'JSON',
                      data: {studentid:studentid},
                                            asyn: false,
                                            success: function(data){
                                            if (data.length) {
                                         }
                                     }
                         });

                       }
                    });
```

When I debug the code, I find that data in success(data) inside child ajax call  contains data from parent ajax call. I want that child should refer to its own data.

Comment: do `async:false` for parent call too.

Comment: why are you using 2 ajax calls?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your parent ajax and your child ajax uses the same response variable `data`.
Try renaming your child ajax's success response to `data1` or something.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/some-url',
  ...
  async: false,
  ...
  success: function (data) {
      if (data.length) {
          $.ajax({
             url: '/other-url',
             ...
             success: function (data1) {
                console.log(data); // the parent response
                console.log(data1); // child response
             }
          });
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: I renamed it to "data1" now it throwing error message data1 is not defined... what error it will be... please  help

Comment: @NidaAmin I added the sample code, so you'll get what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Simply make child success response variable name different the parent success response.

```js
 $.ajax({
              url: '../...',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'JSON',                         
              success: function(data){
                      if (data.length) {

                     // complex and unreadable code
                    // cannot be posted here.

                      $.ajax({
                      url: '../library/index.php?action=librarydetailssearch',
                      type: 'POST',
                      dataType: 'JSON',
                      data: {studentid:studentid},
                                            asyn: false,
                                            success: function(childData){
                                            if (childData.length) {
                                         }
                                     }
                         });

                       }
                    });
```

Comment: it throws "data1 is not defined" error... please help me in telling what error is it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to nest `Ajax` call . Response `data` won't be same for parent and child call .

```js
var postData = {};
callAjax();
function callAjax(){

$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2',
        data:postData,
        success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
              data['call']='First One';
              console.log("==============");
              $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url: 'https://reqres.in/api/unknown',
              data:postData,
                       success: function (data) {
                      console.log("here is "+ JSON.stringify(data)  +data['call']);
              },
              error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         console.log("error occured  : " +thrownError)
                 } 
              });
                  },
          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
       console.log("error occured  : " +thrownError)
             } 
      });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```